# How to get select event from ion-select-option in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, ion-select

I need to implement a “select all” option for an Ionic 4 select list. However, I didn't find a way to fire a (click) or similar event from ion-select-option or ion-select. Any suggestions? Note that solutions for Ionic 3 don't necessarily work vor v4.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Header</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="items" multiple okText="OK" cancelText="Cancel">
    <ion-select-option value="all">Select all</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-options-8kgint?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts)**

.ts

```
  items;

  constructor() {
    this.options.unshift({
      id: -1,
      name: `Select All`
    });
  }

  onChange(evt) {
    if (evt == -1) {
      this.items = this.options.map(x => x.id);
    } else {
      let selectAllIndex = this.items.indexOf(-1);
      this.items.splice(selectAllIndex, 1);
    }
  }
```

.html

```
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="items" multiple okText="OK" cancelText="Cancel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item.id">
            {{ item.name }}
        </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. But the demo doesn't work. The visible items should be all selected/deselected in real time if the option "select all" is being checked or unchecked.

Comment: And it uses Ionic 3 for Angular, not 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using **`ViewChild`** as follows.

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Header</ion-label>
    <ion-select #myselect multiple [(ngModel)]="items" okText="OK" 
             cancelText="Cancel" 
            (ngModelChange)="onChange()" 
            (click)="openSelect(myselect)">
      <ion-option [value]="all" (ionSelect)="selectAll(myselect)">{{all}}</ion-option>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**TS**

```
  items: any = [];

  options = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  all: string = 'select all';

  @ViewChild('myselect') mySelect: Select;

  selectAll(select: Select){
    let selectInputs = select._overlay['data']['inputs'];
    selectInputs.map((array) => array.checked = true);
  }
  openSelect(select: Select){
    select.open();
  }
```

When you click `OK` `button` there will be `select all` in selected items array. If you do not need that you can remove it as below inside `onChange` method when it fires **`ngModelChange`** event as below.

```
onChange() {
  const allIndex = this.items.indexOf(this.all);
  this.items.splice(allIndex, 1);
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-options-aa7oon?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)**

Comment: It's Ionic 3. There is no (ionSelect) in Ionic 4.

Comment: I could not help u because stackblitz is not yet updated to ionic 4

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda do you find any solution. I am also facing same problem. In onic 4 need a Select-All/de-Select-all Button

Comment: @user8462556 Post your question properly in stackoverflow with a stackblitz link and share the question link. then I will try to help you.